# Copying a form programatically using vba in ms-access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I want to programatically copy a form called 'fsubTemplate' to another form called 'fsubInstance' within the same database. I have a good reason for doing this. Is this possible? I'm using ms-access 2007.

Comment: I stronlgy suspect you *don't* really have a good reason for doing this. If you have two forms that are so close in structure, you're creating a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton I actually have 8 identical sub-forms with different names! And yes it WAS a maintenance nightmare until now. That was the whole point of this question!  Now I only need to maintain the 'master' form and using a macro (based on the Docmd.CopyObject method) I can produce the 7 identical copies.  You're probably thinking why do I have 8 identical sub-forms! Well the behaviour of each form is actually different. The behaviour is set in the form's OnLoad event and is based on the forms name. Whether or not this is the right solution, I think I'll raise that as another question.

Comment: Maintaining identical forms is a real problem. It's easy enough to set the properties of a subform in the OnLoad event of the parent form, so that you are always using the same subform, and just altering its appearance/behavior at runtime. Whatever criteria you use to name the subforms and decide which one to load/display is the same criteria you'd use to structure the logic that sets up the specifics for the subform.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [DoCmd.CopyObject Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb237818%28office.12%29.aspx).

```
DoCmd.CopyObject , "fsubInstance", acForm, "fsubTemplate"
```

I didn't supply a value for the first argument, DestinationDatabase, so the destination of the copy will be the current database.